# How do I setup an on-click event listener on content elements in polymer?

Tags: polymer

I'm using polymer 0.8 which I understand has a new API, but I can't find a reference to this issue anywhere. I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
<center-focusable>
    <template is="x-autobind">
        <span on-click="setFocus">test?</span>
    </template>
</center-focusable>
```

Which errors out with:

> [span].[click]: event handler [setFocus] is null in scope ()

My element is defined as such:

```
<dom-module id="center-focusable">
    <template>
        <span on-click="setFocus">I work</span>
        <content></content>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "center-focusable",
        setFocus: function () {
            console.log("test");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: i don't know 8.0 but wouldn't the function call need handlebars? on-click="{{setFocus}}"

Comment: @jimidough10 That API has changed: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/migration.html#declarative-handlers

Comment: good to know. thanks for the link i have been wondering where i could find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've ended up doing is to defined another custom element that will trigger a custom event for me to catch.

```
<dom-module id="focusable-element">
  <content></content>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "focusable-element",
    listeners: {
      'click': 'setFocus'
    },
    setFocus: function () {
      this.fire("center-focusable:center");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Then I'll catch it:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "center-focusable",
    listeners: {
      'center-focusable:center': 'setFocus'
    },
    setFocus: function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log("test");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Together:

```
<center-focusable>
    <focusable-element>
       This works.
    </focusable-element>
</center-focusable>
```

Seems like an unnecessary amount of effort to handle this way though.

Answer (score -1):

`<span>` is a regular HTML element, not a polymer element.
on-click is a polymer syntax.
I think you should use a regular html event : onclick (no dash).
Ex : `<span onclick="console.log('test')">I work</span>`